# Need helping getting a character controller to jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far I have a character controller that enables me to move around, sprint and crouch (no animation) , but I am unable to get the controller to jump. I know 100% the character is getting the input to jump, and the movement vector is around ~40 on the Y axis, so the player should be moving. The problem is, nothing happens. The player can still move around, and fall of ledges, but nothing happens when i press space
This is my code:

```
 using UnityEngine;

 public class KeyboardMovement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private CharacterController controller;
     public float walkSpeed;
     public float sprintSpeed;
     public float crouchSpeed;
     public float jumpHeight;
     Vector3 up = Vector3.zero;
     Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;
     Vector3 forward = Vector3.zero;
     Vector3 sideways = Vector3.zero;
     void Start()
     {
         controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     }


     void Update()
     {
         float speed = walkSpeed;
         //If crouching, set speed to crouch speed. This ovverides sprinting
         if (SingletonSettings.GetKey(SingletonSettings.Keybindings.crouch))
             speed = crouchSpeed;
         //Else if sprinting, set speed to sprint speed
         else if (SingletonSettings.GetKey(SingletonSettings.Keybindings.sprint))
             speed = sprintSpeed;

         //Create vectors for movement
         forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         sideways = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         //up = SingletonSettings.GetKey(SingletonSettings.Keybindings.jump) && controller.isGrounded ? Vector3.up * jumpHeight : Vector3.zero;
         movement = (up * 100) + ((forward + sideways) * 10 * Time.deltaTime * speed);

         //Combine vectors and Multiply by DeltaTime to ensure smooth movement at different framerates.
         //Also multiply by 10*speed to ensure correct speed in different states
          if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
         {
             movement.y = jumpHeight*50 * Time.deltaTime;
         }
         controller.SimpleMove(movement);
     }
     void OnGUI()
     {
         GUILayout.Label('\n' + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movement.y, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
         {
             ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
         }));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharacterController.SimpleMove` from the docs

> Moves the character with speed.
>
> **Velocity along the y-axis is ignored**.
>
> Gravity is automatically applied.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html

---

You should use `CharacterController.Move`

> A more complex move function taking absolute movement deltas.
>
> Attempts to move the controller by motion, the motion will only be constrained by collisions. It will slide along colliders
>
> ...
>
> **This function does not apply any gravity.**
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

With this method, you'll need to apply gravity yourself

```
movement.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

controller.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);
```